# Loading dictionary for input method suggestion list

Tags: android, android-keypad

For various reasons, i'm trying to write my own input keyboard. So far all is going well except that of creating the suggestions.

I've found the latinIME algorithm, which is all good.

However i'm having major difficulty working out how to load the dictionary in the first place.

I've had a good look round the net, and found various suggestions, but no definitive answers, and i cant seem to get any of them to work.

If anyone has any suggestions on how best to do it, or even better some sample code, that would be brilliant.

Many Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

There is a `BinaryDictionary` inside the LatinIME src code [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=summary).
It loads the dictionary using:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("jni_latinime");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {
        Log.e("BinaryDictionary", "Could not load native library jni_latinime");
    }
}
```

I don't know if you can access it, but try it.